# Контекст выполнения операции

Tags: c#, проектирование, static

Есть класс Dispatcher с набором public методов, которые вызываются извне. Каждый из методов - задача(`Func<Task>`), запускаемая в очереди (в один момент выполняется одна задача).  Каждый из методов имеет большую вложенность выполнения (вызывается множество сервисов и других компонентов в процессе исполнения). На этапе выполнения задачи на разных уровнях вложенности необходимо собирать возникающие ошибки. Появилась идея использовать "Контекст выполнения". То есть какой-то статический класс, доступный везде в процессе выполнения задачи в очереди, чтобы не было необходимости пробрасывать данные(возникающие ошибки) из слоя в слой. Проблема в том, что таких Dispatcher-ов может быть много(а static класс общий для всех). Как лучше реализовать такой контекст выполнения операции в разрезе множество диспетчеров?

Comment: я не понял, вы хотите отдельный статический класс на диспетчер? Или вы хотите обычный логгер пробросить в свои сущности? Или вы не хотите поднимать исключения вверх по стеку?

Comment: Я хочу в рамках потока выполнения собирать ошибки и потом на самом верху их обработать(бизнес-ошибки). Пробрасывать везде специальный класс - не очень красиво, внедрять зависимость- то же самое. Хотелось бы использовать для сбора этих данных общую конструкцию, типа static.

Comment: @Sleeeper а почему вы считаете что пробрасывать везде некоторый класс - некрасиво? Обычно так и делают.

Comment: Ну, нет желания пробрасывать контекст выполнения в каждый из возможных модулей, которые участвуют в расчете. Даже не смотря на то, что используется IOC - придется везде иньектить эту зависимость. Может быть можно более элегантно это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы предложил воспользоваться дочерним контейнером. В таком случае вам надо будет для каждой задачи создать дочерний контейнер, зарегистрировать в нем контекст и резолвить этот контекст только там, где он нужен. 
Как пример:

Интерфейс контекста

```
public interface IExecutionContext
{
  string Name { get; }
}
```

Реализация

```
public class ExecutionContext : IExecutionContext
{
  public string Name { get; private set; }

  public ExecutionContext(string name)
  {
    Name = name;
  }
}
```

Класс, который хочет знать о контексте

```
public class ContextConsumer
{
  IExecutionContext _context;

  public ContextConsumer(IExecutionContext context)
  {
    _context = context;
  }

  public void Action()
  {
    Console.WriteLine(_context.Name);
  }
}
```

Диспетчер, который запускает действие. Он же создает контекст и дочерний контейнер

```
public class Dispatcher
{
  IUnityContainer _rootContainer;

  public Dispatcher(IUnityContainer container)
  {
    _rootContainer = container;
  }

  public void ExecuteSomething(string contextName)
  {
    var childContainer = _rootContainer.CreateChildContainer();

    var context = childContainer
        .Resolve<ExecutionContext>(new ParameterOverride("name", contextName));
    childContainer.RegisterInstance<IExecutionContext>(context);

    var consumer = childContainer.Resolve<ContextConsumer>();
    consumer.Action();
  }
}
```

Как использовать:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
var dispatcher = container.Resolve<Dispatcher>();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  var context = "myAwesomeContext" + i;
  dispatcher.ExecuteSomething(context);
}
```

Вывод

```
myAwesomeContext0
myAwesomeContext1
myAwesomeContext2
myAwesomeContext3
myAwesomeContext4
myAwesomeContext5
myAwesomeContext6
myAwesomeContext7
myAwesomeContext8
myAwesomeContext9
```

Таким образом, все зависимости, что будут резолвиться с дочернего контейнера, могут получить один и тот же контекст выполнения, так как он зарегистрирован как синглтон.

Comment: Спасибо. Видимо это лучший способ, тоже о нем думал. Единственный недостаток - нужно везде иньектить зависимость

Comment: @Sleeeper ну не везде, только там, где её будете использовать. Вы же также и статический класс бы вызывали, везде, где бы его использовали

Answer (score 1):

Ты можешь воспользоваться фабричным паттерном. **Создаёшь фабрику** со статичным методом для создания твоего диспатчера и где нужно его делаешь ;)
Можно посмотреть в сторону выполнения всех задач через **класс `Tasks`**, потому что в нём уже встроена эта логика, он не выбрасывает исключения  во время выполнения, а при вызове `Wait` и `Result` отдаёт коллекцию необработанных исключений (если они есть). Но если нужно как-то восстанавливаться при ошибках такой подход не подойдёт :С

Comment: Я использую IOC контейнер, это и есть фабрика) Интересует как раз, как работает модель TASK, как они собирают исключения (видимо в контексте)

Comment: @Sleeper, во время выполнения таска все необработанные исключения попадают в коллекцию, которая отдаётся в поле Aggregate Exception при вызове Wait или Result